# Unable to retrieve one of the Nested data from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I have the following structure in firebase.

[image]

In order to retrieve the data i am using the following code-

```
 mFirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("androidchat").child("users").child("uid-6")

mFirebaseDatabaseReference?.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError?) {
        callback?.handleData(false, requestType)
    }

    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot?) {
        var userModel: UserModel? = p0?.getValue<UserModel>(UserModel::class.java)

        }
    }
})
```

When onDataChange() is called p0 contains all other data except **group** data.

Here's my dataclass UserModel-

```
data class UserModel(var uid: String? = null,
                 var name: String? = null,
                 var image_url: String? = null,
                 var user_location: String? = null,
                 var email: String? = null,
                 var group: MutableMap<String, Boolean> = mutableMapOf(),
                 var deviceIds : MutableMap<String,String> = mutableMapOf(),
                 var online: Boolean? = null,
                 var unread_group_count: Int? = null,
                 var last_seen_online: String? = null,
                 var last_seen_message_timestamp: String? = null,
                 var admin: Boolean? = null,
                 var delete_till: String? = null,
                 var active: Boolean? = null)
```

Any idea why that data is not coming? here is the screen shot of the data , user has many groups but it shows 0 groups-
[image]

Here is the datasnapshot which i received-

```
DataSnapshot { key = uid-6, value = {deviceIds={cc2583f5a2c92eff=dafO8mlj7aa:APA91bETLdet4b-oUnyYAe-GU68BuI4Sw1iT0jGCkUZdjes-ybA_9ZgHtZO-AoApVXQL9NfatyCgSfPSO74fsCUMY-6AY_8826D5AROVkFlQSUs8VKO5_FswoQceTxZ }, last_seen_message_timestamp=1510664398869, name=Akash Nidhi, uid=uid-6, online=true, user_location=USA-OTHERS, image_url=https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/employees/images/150528664259b8d9f29c385.jpeg} }
```

There's no group inside the datasnapshot!.

**Update** 
Added this line mFirebaseDatabaseReference?.keepSynced(false). It worked few times yesterday and its not working now!

Comment: The `group` data is missing even from the `DataSnapshot`? Weird... are you sure that database screenshot is really reflecting your actual setup?

Comment: @PauloMattos Yes the firebase reference url - https://<--->/androidchat/users/uid-6 when opened in browser its redirecting properly to the exact place which has all data

Comment: show the whole dataClass

Comment: This might be client-side caching issue... was that `group` child created (very!) recently? If so, try temporarily disabling Firebase’s client persistence behaviour and try again.

Comment: This is behaving weirdly! Yesterday night when i tried for the first time it worked, today morning back to the same problem!

Comment: @PeterHaddad I have shared the dataclass above... I am querying for usermodel nothing else.

Comment: @SkyTreasure Have you got your answer?

Comment: @SkyTreasure I have posted my answer. Try this, It may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. But finally, I got the solution. I had the following format of data:

```
{
"name":"Deepak",
"date":"03 April 2018",
"match_number":"3",
"team_name1":"Delhi",
"team_name2":"Punjab"
}
```

I have **removed underscore(_) from match_number, team_name1, and team_name2** and used **matchNumber, teamName1, and teamName2**. Like below

```
 {
    "name":"Deepak",
    "date":"03 April 2018",
    "matchNumber":"3",
    "teamName1":"Delhi",
    "teamName2":"Punjab"
    }
```

It works for me perfectly.Try this, maybe it works for you too.